# iOS7 deleteSections:withRowAnimation: animation bug when deleting last section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a project that populates a UITableView with dynamically created sections. Everything works well, and I am able to add and delete objects within each section as expected.

The script is currently set up to remove a section from the TableView when all the members of that section have been deleted as well. This works fine too, except when I go to delete the last cell on the list, removing the final section creates a weird animation bug. The section/cell deletion animations play as expected, but the separator lines jump up the height of the section header and overlap looking bad. Screen capture isn't working for me put a captured a video with my cellphone, apologies in advance for the quality. The video shows the first two deletes working as they should, then the 3rd and final with the animation problem.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eE0j5tCSRIQ

The code that handles the deleting is as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //Set active floor key
        NSObject *key = [[[[self patientList] allKeys]sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]objectAtIndex: indexPath.section];
        [[self tableView]beginUpdates];
        //Delete
        [[self managedObjectContext]deleteObject:[self getPatientFromIndexPath: indexPath]];
        [[[self patientList]objectForKey: key]removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        //Save
        [[self managedObjectContext]save: nil];

        //Delete section if no patients left
        if ([[[self patientList]objectForKey: key]count] == 0) {
            [[self patientList]removeObjectForKey:key];
            [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimationFade)];
        }
        [[self tableView]endUpdates];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
```

Couldn't find anything about this and I'm new to iOS programming so I'm at a loss.

Comment: You should have a look at NSFetchedResultsController, which would make your task a lot easier.

Comment: I'll definitely read up on that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error has been fixed in iOS 8